# JNI4Net C# To Java

Tags: java, c#, .net, jni4net

I have a simple Java class called `jniBridge.Calculator` that has one simple method `Add(int a, int b)`. After building the project using eclipse, i exported the project as a JAR file.

I then called proxygen on the JAR file, this produced a folder called `clr` and another folder called `jvm` that contained both the C# and Java proxies respectively. Proxygen also created a `build.cmd` and an `.xml` files as well.

After that i ran the `build.cmd` it produced a `.DLL` and `.JAR` file.

Now i want to use these or whatever in C#, so i copied the .DLL and .JAR files into the .NET project folder and added a reference to the `.DLL` file and set the `.JAR` file to `Copy Always` to the output folder so that it exists along side the `.EXE` file. I also added a reference to the Jni4Net main library file `jni4net.n-0.8.6.0.dll` and copied its main JAR file, `jni4net.j-0.8.6.0.jar`, to the same directory. Adding to the dump, i also added the original JAR file i started with.

Inside the C# `Program.cs` i do the following:

```
BridgeSetup bs = new BridgeSetup();
bs.AddAllJarsClassPath(".");

Bridge.CreateJVM(bs);
Bridge.RegisterAssembly(typeof(jniBridge.Calculator).Assembly);
```

However, the last invocation fails with the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: net.sf.jni4net.jni.JNIException: Can't load java class for jnibridge.Calculator from classLoader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@e39a3e ---> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jnibridge.Calculator

Any help please!!